# Interpolate and export the following points

Tags: qgis, interpolation, excel, terrascan

I have two crossections of the same position.
I am looking for a way to interpolate the blue points from the attached image.

I need the xyz values of the interpolated points, how can I do this?

[image]

I use QGIS. But the points are exported from Terrascan. I tried to come up with a calculation in Excel.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I use QGIS. But the points are exported from Terrascan. I tried to come up with a calculation in excel but I guess there has to be an easier way?